# Convert videos to 1080p without re-encoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, video-encoding

I have a large amount of 1280x1024 videos and I want to archive them on YouTube. The issue is that YouTube doesn't offer any height between 1080 and 720 and so the video gets scaled down to 900x720, decreasing the quality.

Is there a format, conversion, or piece of metadata (preferably usable with `ffmpeg`) that can "fake" the height so that YouTube treats it as 1080p? I don't want to re-encode the videos since that can lead to additional loss of quality, and the process would also take a considerable amount of time. The videos are in H.264.

I imagine, if this is possible, the end result would either cause YouTube to resample or pad the video to somewhere between 1280x1080 and 1350x1080.

One way that seems working is to use `-aspect 1280:1080`. While that causes some distortion, it is only 5% stretch and it works, but I am still wondering whether there exists a better way.

Comment: Resolution cannot be changed without re-encoding. Even though you see transcoded versions when you view a video on YT, they, afaik, preserve the original files. Which you can retrieve using Google Takeout. Confirm this part with someone else, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that concatenating two MKV files produces a video that is recognized by YouTube as 1080p even if only the first video has the proper dimensions. This can be accomplished by first creating a very short video with the same parameters as the original one (for example with `-vframes 1`) but upscaled to the desired size (with `-vf scale=-1:1080`). As long as the streams and probably some other parameters as well match, you can then use the [`concat` demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer) to join the videos. Even though the result may not be playable, YouTube will accept it.